# VHDL: Metastability check for hold time fails

Tags: vhdl, metastability

I'm trying to model an [SN74HC573](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc573.pdf) D-type latch in VHDL to get back into it. Here's what I got so far:

```
-- simple model of a SN74AHC573 D-type Transparent Latch
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- entity declaration
entity sn74ahc573 is
    port ( oe_n, le : in std_logic;     -- control signals
           d : in std_logic;            -- data input
           q : out std_logic );         -- data output

    -- TODO: add detailed timing constants
    constant t_pd   : delay_length := 9 ns;     -- Propagation delay
    constant t_w    : delay_length := 5 ns;     -- Pulse duration, LE high
    constant t_su   : delay_length := 3.5 ns;   -- Setup time, data before LE falling edge
    constant t_h    : delay_length := 1.5 ns;   -- Hold time, data after LE falling edge
end entity sn74ahc573;

-- rtl architecture to check metastability
architecture rtl of sn74ahc573 is
    signal intern : std_logic := 'X';
begin

    -- concurrent replacement of behavioral process
    -- TODO: replace with state machine for more precise propagation delays
    intern <= 'Z' when oe_n = '1' else              -- high-impedance state
               d  when oe_n = '0' and le = '1' else -- latch input
               unaffected;                          -- else, nothing happens

    -- check metastability of latch enable signal
    checkMetaStability : process is
    begin
        -- wait for LE falling edge
        wait until falling_edge(le);

        --check pulse width
        assert le'delayed'stable(t_w)
            report "LE pulse width too short!"
            severity failure;

        -- check setup time
        assert intern'delayed'stable(t_su)
            report "Input changed during setup time!"
            severity failure;

        -- check hold time
        wait for t_h;
        assert intern'delayed'stable(t_h + t_su)
            report "Input signal changed during hold time!"
            severity failure;

    end process checkMetaStability;

    -- update output
    q <= intern;

end architecture rtl;
```

I'm having trouble with the process checking metastability. Checking for pulse width and setup time works, but checking hold time will fail:

```
-- Test Bench for SN74AHC573 model
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- entity declaration
entity sn74ahc573_tb is
end entity sn74ahc573_tb;

-- test bench architecture
architecture test_bench of sn74ahc573_tb is
    signal oe_n, le, d, q : std_logic := '0';
begin

    dut : entity work.sn74ahc573(rtl)
        port map ( oe_n, le, d, q );

    stimulus : process is
    begin
        -- start in high-Z mode
        oe_n <= '1'; wait for 10 ns;

        -- WARNING: These signal changes violate metastability
        oe_n <= '0'; le <= '1'; d <= '1'; wait for 4 ns;
            -- violate minimal pulse width
        -- le <= '0'; wait for 1 ns;
            -- violate setup time
        -- d <= '0';  wait for 1 ns;
        -- le <= '0'; wait for 1 ns;
            -- violate hold time
         wait for 1 ns; le <= '0';
         wait for 1 ns; d <= '0';

        -- wait forever
        wait;

    end process stimulus;

end architecture test_bench;
```

This test bench will "fail" for pulse width and setup time, but not when checking hold time. What am I missing?

I'm using GHDL 0.36-dev on Arch Linux.

Comment: If the input is not repetitive, can you hold forever?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referencing; I want to check whether the signal `intern` changes within 1.5 ns after `LE`'s falling edge.

Comment: got it....,,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering because I can't comment.

You have deasserted `le` before changing the input `d` in your testbench.

In the DUT, however,

```
intern <= 'Z' when oe_n = '1' else              -- high-impedance state
           d  when oe_n = '0' and le = '1' else -- latch input
           unaffected;                          -- else, nothing happens
```

As `intern` is **`unaffected`** when `le` is deasserted and `oe_n` is asserted (`0`), it holds the previous value of `d` (in this case `1`). When you check for the hold time, no matter how long you wait, the assert will not fail.

```
    -- check hold time
    wait for t_h;
    assert intern'delayed'stable(t_h + t_su)
```

This change in testbench (similar to what you have done for setup violation) should solve the problem. By deasserting `le` after input `d` changes, the `hold` check should fail.

```
stimulus : process is
begin
    -- start in high-Z mode
    oe_n <= '1'; wait for 10 ns;

    -- WARNING: These signal changes violate metastability
    oe_n <= '0'; le <= '1'; d <= '1'; wait for 4 ns;

    -- violate setup time
    -- d <= '0';  wait for 1 ns;
    -- le <= '0'; wait for 1 ns;

    -- violate hold time
     d <= '0';
     wait for 1 ns; le <= '0';

    -- wait forever
    wait;

end process stimulus;
```

Comment: It's not entirely what I'm looking for, since signal `d` needs to change *after* the `le` falling edge for a hold time violation. But I believe your general assessment is correct, I'll have a look again and come back when I had time to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Vinay Madapura's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/139289/vinay-madapura) answer, I found the error. I modified my signal assignments to this:

```
-- latch the input according to LE state
intern <= d when le = '1' else
          unaffected;

-- update output
q <= intern when oe_n = '0' else
     'Z';
```

This reflects the overall behavior better than my old code. The input is now correctly latched into `intern` regardless of `oe_n`'s state.